# Linux,I want to set user passwd which contains the username,How to set passwd policy?

Tags: linux, passwords, passwd

I hava know a litter about linux passwd policy,I have establish a new user

```
useradd testuser
```

And I want to set the testuser's passwd  as `abtestuserab`
I input

```
passwd testuser
```

the input `abtestuserab`
It's failded,the terminal reported

```
BAD PASSWORD: The password contains the user name in some form
```

So,how to make the passwd valid.
the /etc/pam.d/system-auth is like this

```
auth        required      pam_tally2.so onerr=fail deny=10 unlock_time=600 root_unlock_time=600 audit
auth        required      pam_env.so
auth        sufficient    pam_unix.so nullok try_first_pass
auth        requisite     pam_succeed_if.so uid >= 1000 quiet_success
auth        required      pam_deny.so

account     required      pam_unix.so
account     sufficient    pam_localuser.so
account     sufficient    pam_succeed_if.so uid < 1000 quiet
account     required      pam_permit.so

password    requisite     pam_pwquality.so minlen=9 try_first_pass local_users_only retry=3 authtok_type= enforce_for_root ocredit=0 lcredit=-1 ucredit=-1 dcredit=-1 [badw
ords=first2012++]
password    required      pam_pwhistory.so remember=10 use_authtok enforce_for_root
password    sufficient    pam_unix.so sha512 shadow nullok try_first_pass use_authtok
password    required      pam_deny.so

session     optional      pam_keyinit.so revoke
session     required      pam_limits.so
-session     optional      pam_systemd.so
session     [success=1 default=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so service in crond quiet use_uid
session     required      pam_unix.so
```

Comment: I don't want to steal your fire, but there is a reason it's setup like that... :|

Comment: We need a common passwd for our servers.the other server is the same passwd.But this setting has some problem in CentOS7

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Following works for me:

```
/tmp ❯❯❯ sudo su
[sudo] password for wani: 
/tmp # ❯❯❯ useradd testuser
/tmp # ❯❯❯ echo -e "abtestuserab\nabtestuserab" | passwd testuser
Changing password for user testuser.
New password: BAD PASSWORD: The password contains the user name in some form
Retype new password: passwd: all authentication tokens updated successfully.
/tmp # ❯❯❯
```

If I am `root` user, then the `BAD PASSWORD` text is just a warning.

Comment: I have tried this way,but it reported`New password: Password change aborted.
passwd: Have exhausted maximum number of retries for service`,may be there  the passwd valid policy must be changed

Comment: @elsonwx Delete the user and try again ?

Comment: I commented the rule after pam_pwquality.so,it's working haha